# SelectionChanged Combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, xaml, combobox

I want to populate a `ComboBox` based on selection of other `ComboBox`.
Both combo boxes are populate from database using WCF.
My problem is that on first selection it's not working (just after second selection it's work and it's show results from first selection).

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox 
   x:Name="selClientCombo" 
   SelectionChanged="listEchipamente" 
   IsEditable="True" 
   SelectedIndex="-1" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="455,35,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   Width="215" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
<ComboBox 
   x:Name="selEchipamentCombo" 
   HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
   Margin="457,65,0,0" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   Width="213" 
   ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
```

**code**

```
  private void listEchipamente(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            List<string> echipamenteWCF = client.getEchipament(selClientCombo.Text).ToList();

            MessageBox.Show(" Client Selected !");
            if (selEchipamentCombo.Items.Count >0)
            {
                selEchipamentCombo.Items.Clear();
            }
                for (int i = 0; i < echipamenteWCF.Count(); i++)
                {
                    selEchipamentCombo.Items.Add(echipamenteWCF[i]);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time `SelectionChanged` is fired, the `Text` has not been updated (and hence it holds the previous value).

You should access the underlying data item to get the Text instead:

```
if(selClientCombo.SelectedItem == null) return;
List<string> echipamenteWCF = 
                   client.getEchipament(selClientComo.SelectedItem.ToString()).ToList();
...
```

I supposed the `ToString()` will resolve the display Text. You can always cast `SelectedItem` to the actual type and access its string property (being  shown as Text) easily. You can also access the `SelectedValue` with condition that some `SelectedValuePath` is set for the ComboBox.